# Капча на кириллице

Tags: php, кодировка, captcha

Делаю капчу на кириллице из ttf шрифтов.
язык разработки php.
задаю массив из латиницы и(или) чисел - работает.
задаю массив из кириллицы - кракозябры.
В чем может быть ошибка?

```
function vam_random_charcode($length) {
$arraysize = 33; 
$chars = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ж','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ы','Э','Ю','Я');
      $code = '';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
        $j = floor(vam_rand(0,$arraysize));
        $code .= $chars[$j];
        }
        return  $code;
        }
```

Comment: в том, что шрифты без кириллицы?

Comment: шрифт, например стандартный Arial.ttf, т.е кириллица в нем есть

Comment: @kovalsky2010, кодировка страниц?

Comment: @Deonis

UTF-8
в .htaccess AddDefaultCharset utf-8 прописан
да и вряд ли кодировка страниц, так как генерируется то картинка

Comment: Картинка может и генерируется, но вопрос - из каких символов? Пробовали вывести на экран результат *$code*? Возможно, что надо преобразовывать кодировку строки "в добровольно-принудительном порядке". 

    iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1251', $code);

Comment: @Deonis

Call to undefined function iconv() 
нет функции получается )))) дела....
Щас попробую разобраться

Comment: @kovalsky2010, за последнее время - это самое удивительное, что вижу ;) [iconv()][1] введена начиная с версии PHP4. Не хотите ж вы сказать, что у вас версия старее? ))

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php

Comment: А кодировка файла тоже UTF8 стоит у вас?

Comment: @Drimean
да. Все перепробовал.
iconv()  тоже не помогла

Comment: @kovalsky2010, а попробуйте каждую букву в массиве обернуть в utf8_encode или urlencode, а потом расшифровывать обратными к этим функциями.

Comment: @kovalsky2010, и если не поможет, скиньте ссылку на phpinfo();

Comment: **капча на кириллице** 

вы учавствуете в конкурсе на самый неудобный сайт ? (поставьте ее  на обновление страницы)